# Pegar o id do botão pressionado

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Como posso pegar o id do botão pressionado, sendo que os botões são gerados automaticamente com php e não tem o seu id fixo, preciso do id do botão para fazer uma consulta SQL com o php,

Código que gera o botão:

```
 while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($ids))
              {
                  $query = ("select * from componentes where id_principal = ".$linha[0]." ");
                  $componentes = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                  $resultado = mysqli_fetch_row($componentes);

                  $id_componente = $resultado[0];
                  $codigo = $resultado[2];
                  $nome = $resultado[3];
                  $entrada = $resultado[4];
                  $saida = $resultado[5];
                  $f = $resultado[6];
                  $m = $resultado[7];
                  $g = $resultado[8];
                  $gg = $resultado[9];
                  $total = ($f + $m + $g + $gg);

                  print "<tr>";
                  // ESSE É O BOTÃO QUE PRECISO PEGAR O ID QUANDO ELE SER PRESSIONADO
                  print "<td><button id=".$id_componente." type='submit' class='btn btn-success'>".$codigo."</td>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma classe dos elementos gerados, por exemplo

> class='btn btn-success **teste**'

e então:

```
$(".teste").click(function()
{
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: Somente com o ajax para passar esse valor para o php?

Comment: de forma direta sim, ou você poderia utilizar uma forma menos convencional, criar um input hidden, preencher com o valor desse id e dar um submit no form

Comment: Teria como eu relacionar esse input hidden com o botão que foi pressionado?

Comment: $("input[name=input_teste]").val(id);

Comment: com esse código dentro da função mencionada acima você já dá o valor do id para o value do input

Comment: E eu preciso criar o input ou esse código jquery já cria ele? depois de submitar o form com post, eu pego o valor com php assim né : $_POST['input_teste']

Comment: Muito boa a sua resposta, parabéns.

Comment: Exatamente, você cria o input e depois pega o valor como você mencionou. Obrigado, fico feliz por ajudar!

Answer (score 2):

Adicione uma classe e coloque o evento na mesma para pegar o `id` do botão:

```
<?
 while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($ids))
              {
                  $query = ("select * from componentes where id_principal = ".$linha[0]." ");
                  $componentes = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                  $resultado = mysqli_fetch_row($componentes);

                  $id_componente = $resultado[0];
                  $codigo = $resultado[2];
                  $nome = $resultado[3];
                  $entrada = $resultado[4];
                  $saida = $resultado[5];
                  $f = $resultado[6];
                  $m = $resultado[7];
                  $g = $resultado[8];
                  $gg = $resultado[9];
                  $total = ($f + $m + $g + $gg);

                  print "<tr>";
                  // ESSE É O BOTÃO QUE PRECISO PEGAR O ID QUANDO ELE SER PRESSIONADO
                  print "<td><button id=".$id_componente." type='submit' class='btn btn-success bt-componente'>".$codigo."</td>";

?>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.bt-componente').click(function(){
             var id = $(this).attr('id'); //aqui você tem o id para usar em um ajax ou algo do tipo...
             $.ajax({
                 url: "urlquefaraaconsulta",
                 type: "post", //opcional, padrão get
                 data: {id: id},
                 success: function(data){
                     $('table').after(data); //exemplo de como inserir o conetúdo retornado
                 }
             });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Outra alternativa seria redirecionar o usuário diretamente pra uma tela em que fará a consulta utilizando o `id` como parâmetro:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.bt-componente').click(function(){
         var id = $(this).attr('id');
         window.location.href = "minhaurl?id=" + id;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Somente com o ajax para passar esse valor para o php?

Comment: Usando `jQuery` sim, tem algumas formas de fazer mas o conceito é o mesmo...vou adicionar um exemplo

Comment: Certo, obrigado

Comment: Na hora de inserir ali tem várias formas de fazer, ai vai depender de onde no seu `html` vai inserir o retorno, como ele vai retornar...

Comment: Adicionei mais uma sugestão.

Answer (score 1):

Você poder usar a função [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) do jQuery para obter o valor de atributos:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="botao1">Botão</button>
<button id="botao2">Botão</button>
```

Comment: Somente com o ajax para passar esse valor para o php?

Comment: Depende @RobertoAlbino. Com Ajax tende a ficar mais performático por não dar refresh na tela.

Comment: Entendi, é porque eu tenho alguns problemas de sincronia usando ajax, nunca consigo pegar o valor no momento que eu preciso.

Comment: Quais seriam esses problemas?

Comment: A consulta é excutada nula por não ter o valor do ajax, e depois dela ter sido executada é que eu recebo o valor do ajax.

Comment: "A consulta é excutada nula por não ter o valor do ajax", como assim? E é normal receber o valor depois de executado

Comment: No momento que o php faz a consulta sql o valor da variavel está vazio, só depois da consulta ter sido executada, é que o valor da variavel é preenchido pelo ajax, um problema de sincronia entre o meu codigo php e o ajax.